# Why is the server sometimes serving the wrong version of a webpage?

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I recently changed the signup page for a site.  It's working for some, but for others it's failing.

For whatever reason, the server is sometimes getting confused and running the old query.

Hosting support stated they don't have any serverside PHP cacheing.  OSCommerce cache is turned off.  phpBB is the forum software, but only the forum database is involved here.  What else to check?

ANSWER:

Check whether or not there's a second sign-up form hidden elsewhere on the site.

Nothing to see here!  Move along!

Comment: _"It looks like some people are getting the old signup page, which then tries to insert forum info into the store db, where it no longer goes"_ Please explain. The old signup page does post something to a PHP file, right? Is that file different from the new signup page? Then simply put a redirect in the old one, pointing visitors to the new page. If it's the same file that processes the new signups, then why does the data get inserted in the old database?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. The client's browser may cache content delivered before. Inserting data into the database is done at serverside when your script is executed - and this is only executed when requested by client and the client does not cache ... How can cached content trigger inserting data into the wrong database? When there is no code doing this wrong inserts on your server anymore?!

Comment: D'oh!  Totally correct.  No way client-side caching is the whole story.  See the edits for more information about the state of the server.

Comment: Are you able to restart mysql? Maybe it is something with db-connection pooling. I am not familar with neither php nor phpbb ...

Comment: Not directly, but I'm having support flush the MySQL cache.

Comment: See the edited question for an amazing, complicated, technical solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making it reload with something like a header()

```
session_register("mysess");
$mysess++;
if ( $mysess < 2 ) { header("Location: mypage.php"); }
```

Thats un-tested but mite give you somewhere to start.

Comment: That's a great "why not try this for your weird problem?" suggestion.  Thanks.